# Alternation of functions Python

Tags: python, function, cycle, dayofweek

I am writing a small project for study. I want to ask for advice.
There are two functions that should change every 7 days. The beginning of the report on September 5, the end of June 30.
For example, 5-11 `upper` week, 12-18-`lower` week, etc.
The script will constantly turn to the current function.
I will answer all your questions in the comments)

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking but... You can use `%`.  Perhaps like this: `if day - 5 % 7 == 0: upper = not upper`.  If `upper == True` call `upper()` and if `upper == False` call `lower`.

Comment: I need that when addressing a function, let's say `week()`, she returns the function that `upper()` or `lower()` shakes the reference point